# Cannot use cvDilate with some structure element

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am very new to Emgu cv and C#. I am trying to use cvDilate method with structure element = [1 1 1] and then the error occurred.

Here is the code:

```
private void btnRotate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[,] tempStructure = {{1,1,1}};
            StructuringElementEx s = new StructuringElementEx(tempStructure,1,0);
            Image<Gray, Byte> tempBinarized = binarizedPicture.Copy();
            binarizedPicture.Dispose();
            Image<Gray, Byte> destPtr = new Image<Gray, byte>(tempBinarized.Size);
            IntPtr src = tempBinarized.Ptr;
            IntPtr dst = destPtr.Ptr;
            IntPtr ele;
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(tempStructure, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            try
            {
                ele = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (handle.IsAllocated)
                {
                    handle.Free();
                }
            }

            Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvDilate(src, dst, ele, ITERATE);               
            Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCopy(dst, destPtr, IntPtr.Zero);
            actionBox.Image = destPtr.ToBitmap();
```

and Here is the Error Message:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that     other memory is corrupt.
  Source=Emgu.CV
  StackTrace:
       at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvDilate(IntPtr src, IntPtr dst, IntPtr element, Int32     iterations)
       at testMaster.Form1.btnRotate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Wep    API\Project\TestMaster\testMaster\testMaster\Form1.cs:line 91
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32  clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,  IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at     System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods. IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at testMaster.Program.Main() in d:\Wep API\Project\TestMaster\testMaster\testMaster\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

When I changed the structure element to some other value (ex: [1 0 1]), it works fine. So I don't know why this happens. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried by freeing the handle AFTER calling cvDilate() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a quick test using this more emgu oriented code, i.e. I use cvinvoke only to perform dilation and have no problem applying a custom structuring element:

```
       //Create a grayscale image
       Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>(400, 400);
       // Fill image with random values
       img.SetRandUniform(new MCvScalar(), new MCvScalar(255));
       // Create and initialize histogram
       ImageViewer.Show(img);
       //Create structuring element
       int[,] tempStructure = { { 1, 1, 1 } };
       StructuringElementEx element = new StructuringElementEx(tempStructure, 1, 0);
       //Apply dilation using element
       CvInvoke.cvDilate(img, img, element, 2);
       ImageViewer.Show(img);
```